# Why Angular2 says Component is not defined though it's present there?

Tags: angular

My `app.component.ts :`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello Angular 2</h1><courses></courses>',
    directives: [CoursesComponent] 
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

My `courses.component.ts :`

```
   import {component} from 'angular2/core';

   @Component({
    selector : 'courses',
    template : '<h2>Courses</h2>'
   })
   export class CoursesComponent{

   }
```

Though all the details are there I am not sure why still  chromebug says that "component is not defined" .

The error is :

```
ReferenceError: Component is not defined
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/boot.js
    at eval (courses.component.ts:3)
    at execute (courses.component.ts:7)
    at ensureEvaluated (system.src.js:3186)
    at ensureEvaluated (system.src.js:3178)
    at ensureEvaluated (system.src.js:3178)
    at Object.execute (system.src.js:3304)
    at doDynamicExecute (system.src.js:703)
    at link (system.src.js:905)
    at doLink (system.src.js:557)
    at updateLinkSetOnLoad (system.src.js:605)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: `directives` is deprecated, we use `declaration` in the ngModule now :)

Comment: @AJT_82   So how should I be changing the code ? And is the error due that I am seeing due to depreciation ?

Comment: just a quick question, are you still using angular in its beta stages because you are importing from `angular2/core` instead of `@angular/core`. even your directive declaration is using the old way

Comment: Nice catch @Hamed, overlooked that one ;) Yes, The Dark Night. Check which version of Angular you are using. Also as a reminder, many tutorials out there is deprecated, I suggest you check the official docs, which are up to date (v 4) in case you are using latest Angular version. https://angular.io/

Comment: @Hamed Hmmm... seems there are so many depreciated stuff over here . Let  me check that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`directives` in `@Component()` are deprecated since `2.0.0 beta.6`.
Register them in `@NgModule()` instead

```
@Component({
    ...,
    directives: [CoursesComponent] 
})
```

you need to add it to

```
@NgModule({
    declaration: [CoursesComponent],
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In courses.component.ts you have the next code line:

```
 import {component} from 'angular2/core';
```

And it should be

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

You are using @Component which could not be resolved if you don't import it.